# dehighlight the Layer when another layer is clicked Leaflet Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

I use Leaflet in Vuejs. I load GeoJSON data on map and I want to highlight a layer(Polygon) when I click on it. That works fine. But when I click on the second layer, I want the first layer to be dehighlighted. Dehighliting of the first layer does not work when I click on second layer. Here is a part of my function which I highlight and try to dehighlight:

```
 makeEditable(feature, layer) {

    var highlight = {
      'color': '#FFFF00',
      'weight': 2,
      'opacity': 1
    };

    var previouscolor = {
      'color': '#5dbcd2',
      'weight': 2,
      'opacity': 1
    };
    var selected
    var previous
    layer.on('click', function (e) {

        e.target.setStyle(highlight);

        if (selected !== null) {
          previous = selected;
        }

        selected = e.target;

      if (previous) {
        layer.setStyle(previouscolor);
        }
    });
  }
```

Here is also my computed:

```
 computed: {
  options() {
    return {
      onEachFeature: this.makeEditable,
    }
  }
}
```

and I also defined a method to load GeoJSON from DB, which in called in mounted:

```
  async loadGeoJSON() {
    try {
      this.geojson = await api.getCurrentZones();
    } catch (error) {
      this.error = error.message;
      this.notifyVue();
    }
  },
```

Any suggestion that how can I dehighlight my layer? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to mark the selected element with a css class, e.g. with

```
e.originalEvent.target.classList.add('selected')
```

(You need `originalEvent` here, because events are wrapped by leaflet.js with the original DOM event contained in this attribute)

The css class `selected` can then be defined with normal css, although you need to remember that polygons in leaflet.js are `path` elements in SVG, so `color` won't work. Instead, use `stroke` and `fill` like that:

```
.selected {
   stroke: #FFFF00;
   fill: #FFFF00;
}
```

To unselect a previously selected element, you can use

```
document.querySelectorAll('.selected').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('selected'))
```

You should do that *before* setting the class of the newly selected element.